# Continuity in Probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

[image: Property 4]

Could someone give me a simple explanation of property 4?

Context: Currently learning a bit of financial mathematics on my own to see if it is a field I really want to get into. The first 3 properties make it a stochastic process but the 4th condition I am unfamiliar with. The fourth property to me seems to limit how big the growth from one point to another is, but I am unsure if the interpretation is correct or not.

Comment: Quote seems to come from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Mathematical_definition

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, property 4 states that there are no *step discontinuities* in the cumulative density function.

$$\neg\exists \epsilon > 0:\;\lim\limits_{h\searrow 0}\;\mathsf P\big(\big\lvert X_{t+h}{-}X_t\big\rvert> \epsilon\big) > 0$$

Comment: I am not sure it quite that, but more about limits: a Poisson process has discrete jumps, but is a Lévy process.  Isn't this about limits as time intervals reduce to zero, and might be closer to saying something informally like "any change in infinitesimal time is almost surely infinitesimal"?

Comment: I am still not quite sure I get that. My initial interpretation is that the distance between a value of a RV at a certain time and a value of it afterwards cannot exceed a certain amount. In context I am trying to learn more about financial mathematics so I assumed it meant that a company in the long run cannot grow infinitely and will eventually stop at a certain point.

Comment: @Henry Yes, that's what it is saying.  The change in the random variable after an infinitesimal period (limit down to zero) is almost surely infinitesimal: there are no sudden impulses.

Comment: There can be sudden impulses, it is just they are unlikely to happen in infinitesimal time.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret it the way that Henry does in the comments on Graham Kemp's answer: Heuristically, any change in infinitesimal time is almost surely infinitesimal (i.e., is infinitesimal with probability one).

Comment: I am still not quite sure what infinitesimal is, I tried looking it up and it is the same as a differential which is just a very small change in something but I still don't quite get what the property is trying to say..... Is it possible, in Reddit's terms, explain it like I'm five.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure I'm able to do that.  (Not saying it can't be done, just saying I might not be up to it.)  You can think of an infinitesimal, intuitively, as the "opposite" of an infinitely large quantity: It's smaller than any positive quantity (just as an infinitely large value is larger than any finite quantity), but it is, in some sense, an "inclination"—a tendency toward a finite value.  But ultimately, any proper explanation will require a discussion of limits.

Comment: Hmm would it be correct to say then that if we set some large ϵ that as we get closer to our original time, the probability of such a jump would be 0? So this property is to limit how explosive our jumps are?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation:
It serves to exclude process with jumps at fixed (nonrandom) times.
See P68 of R. Cont/P.Tankov